# How to analyze a tx data?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, decoding

Given a transaction of type `types.Transaction` (golang `go-ethereum`), how can I analyze the `data` field and check if it has a swap or a sync event?
I know that `0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1` is Uniswap v2's `Sync(uint112,uint112)` but how can I extract the topics out of the transaction's data to check if it is present?

Context: I am looking at Arbitrum's WS sequencer feed, so the tx has not yet been published on chain and I cannot query the logs.

Answer (score 1):

`types.Transaction` does not hold any events, or any post-block-inclusion information. But `types.Receipt` does. You can get the receipt of a transaction pretty easily from its hash (only if the transaction has already been included in a block):

```go
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func getTransactionReceipt(ethClient *ethclient.Client, tx *types.Transaction) (*types.Receipt, error) {
    return ethClient.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), tx.Hash())
}
```

The `Logs` property on `types.Receipt` holds all the events for that transaction, represented by the `types.Log` types, which itself has a `Topics` member, holding the topics:

```go
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

var uniV2SyncTopic = common.HexToHash("0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1")

func handleUniV2SyncEvents(ethClient *ethclient.Client, tx *types.Transaction) {
    txReceipt, err := ethClient.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), tx.Hash())
    if err != nil {
        // handle the error
    }

    for _, log := range txReceipt.Logs {
        if log.Topics[0] == uniV2SyncTopic {
            // do something with the log
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the tx has not already been included in the block, I am looking at the WS feed from Arbitrum Sequencer.

Answer (score 1):

Take under note that I'm the author of this package and that it's still not fully completed (not in main, missing tests, etc...)

You can see the code of how to unpack logs here: https://github.com/unpackdev/solgo/tree/liquidity/bytecode

Specifically take a look here:
https://github.com/unpackdev/solgo/blob/liquidity/bytecode/log.go

What you need to do is following:

Everything you need starts with `types.Receipt`. Once you have transaction, you need to fetch receipt. Within receipt, you'll have status if transaction executed successfully including `types.Log`.

- Within logs, there are topics. 0th topic is signature.
- Remaining of the topics will be related to arguments that are passed within the event/signature.
- `log.Data` basically the event data payload.

Now you need to be aware of one crucial thing. Logs within transaction can be and usually are related to different contracts. Each log has Address entry and you'll need to have ABI for that contract in order to properly and safely decode the log.

Example code:

```go
func (p *TransactionsProcessor) decodeLogs(entry *TransactionEntry) error {
    if len(entry.Receipt.Logs) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    for _, log := range entry.Receipt.Logs {
        if logContract, ok := entry.LogContracts[log.Address]; ok {
            logEntry, err := logContract.DecodeLog(p.ctx, log)
            if err != nil {
                zap.L().Error(
                    "failed to decode log",
                    zap.Error(err),
                    zap.Any("network_id", entry.NetworkID),
                    zap.String("network", entry.Network.String()),
                    zap.Any("strategy", entry.Strategy),
                    zap.Uint64("block_number", entry.BlockHeader.Number.Uint64()),
                    zap.String("tx_hash", entry.Transaction.Hash().String()),
                    zap.Uint("log_index", log.Index),
                    zap.String("log_address", log.Address.String()),
                )
                continue
            }

            entry.Logs = append(entry.Logs, logEntry)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

https://github.com/unpackdev/solgo/blob/a118d2fec19b1a1d9f2331095e948bca94595b27/observers/transactions.go#L365

Hope this helps!